# Alternative Proof of Hoeffding's Lemma / solve the equation $E[1_A | X] = (1+X)/2$ given $X$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

In the context of proving the [Hoeffding Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_lemma)  I came across a slightly weaker statement in the form of an exercise:

"If $X$ is a real valued random variable and $|X| \leq 1$ a.s. then there exists a random variable $Y$ with values in $\{ -1, +1 \}$ such that
\begin{equation}
E[Y|X] = X \qquad a.s. 
\end{equation} "

I haven't been able to prove it, and the only ansatz that I have is to try to find $A,B \in \mathcal{F}$ with $Y = 1_{A} - 1_{B} $ such that

\begin{equation}
P(A|X) = E[1_A|X] = (1+X)/2 \qquad P(B|X) = E[1_B|X] = (1-X)/2 
\end{equation}

However I do not know if I can find such measurable sets $A,B$ ? (Maybe some more stronger assumptions need to be imposed ? )